# Error consulta cakephp utilizando between

Tags: mysql, cakephp

Estoy realizando una consulta con between pero no me devuelve ningún error y tampoco ninguna fila. Pero si hay casos donde se cumplen las condiciones que le pongo a la consulta. Si quito la condición de between me lo devuelve pero cuando pongo esa condición es cuando no me devuelve nada.

```
$tarea = $this->Signs->find('all',[
                    'conditions'=> array(
                        'date_inicio BETWEEN "'.$horaInicio->format('Y-m-d H:i:s').'" and "'.$horaFin->format('Y-m-d H:i:s').'"')
                        ])
                        ->where(['user_id' => $horario->user_id,'date_fin IS NOT' => null]);
```

Comment: verifica en tu tabla que realmente la columna en la que estas haciendo la consulta es un DATE, porque si es un Varchar o un Text no te funcionará correctamente.

Answer (score 0):

Prueba a juntar todas las condiciones en la consulta en lugar de agregarlas en dos partes.

```
$conditions = array(
    'conditions' => array(
        'date_inicio BETWEEN "'.$horaInicio->format('Y-m-d H:i:s').'" and "'.$horaFin->format('Y-m-d H:i:s').'"'), 'user_id' => $horario->user_id,'date_fin IS NOT' => null
    )));
$tarea = $this->Signs->find('all',$conditions);
```